# How to declare Array of objects inside Object in Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-5

I want to create an array of objects inside object.Like this

```
MyMainObject: {
myArray : [{name:string, available:boolean}]
}
```

And push values dynamically to the array

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you describe little more?

Comment: Hi i want to declare and push array of objects inside an object. MyObject: {
myarray : [{name:string, available:boolean}]
}]}.   In this manner

Comment: You can use array:any[] or create a class e.g product containing the objects in your array and declare array:product []

Answer (score 0):

First create interface

```
export interface MainObject {
  myArray: {name: string, available: boolean}[];
}
```

Then use that interface in component.

```
export class MyComponent {
   MyMainObject: MainObject = {} as MainObject;

constructor() {
    this.MyMainObject.myArray.push({ name: 'name', available: true });
    console.log(this.MyMainObject);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Simply declare Object like inside class

    MyMainObject: {
    myArray : []
    };

//nd push value dynamically like inside any method

    if(condition){
    this.MyMainObject['myArray'].push(
    {name:string, available:boolean}
    )
    }
```

Comment: Facing issue:  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
[Code-Ref(Stackblitz)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rly3s1)

Comment: Can you please post your code?